# c# SendMessage not work when process window is minimized

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I' have searching many answer say that SendMessage() can click through minimised window.

But I'm trying to click a mouse left button to a minimised application, I use this c# code below and it's not working.

I'm pretty sure hWnd is correct, because when I focus to the window and it's worked.

```cs
internal class ClickSimulator
{
        private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    
        public static void SimulateClick(nint hWnd, int x, int y)
        {
            IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x);

            // Send the mouse down message
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
    
            // Send the mouse up message
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
        }
}
```

Send left mouse click through minimised window.

Comment: So, are you trying to click on the taskbar icon?  That is not actually your window.  It belongs to Explorer.  Your window is hidden.

Comment: no, i am trying to send message to other process window, it's other game process window, not browser

Comment: There could be many reasons for this to fail.  The app has to map your coordinates into their coordinates, and that computation is going to be screwed up because the window location and size are not right.